# Issue with @media on css

Tags: html, css

I just get a website to give some updates but I've been out of CSS coding for some years and still adapting to the new concepts.

The idea is to give some extra parameters where the actual responsivity is not working well. So what I'm trying to do objectively is to centralize the logo and resize it to be a little bigger.

this is the HTML block regarding this section

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar_nomesistema">
    <div class="navbar-header col-md-3">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">
            <img alt="Brand" src="img/logo_nomesistema.png">
        </a>
    </div>
```

What I need to modify is that img called "logo_nomesistema.png". I tried several different parameters but it's not changing the img. My actual code for this section is:

```
@media screen  and (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar > .container .navbar-brand,
    .navbar > .container-fluid .navbar-brand > img {
        min-width: 200px;
    }
}

@media screen  and (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-collapse > .navbar-header > .navbar-brand > img {
        min-width: 200px;
    }
}
```

As you can see I have two different options because I'm not sure that I'm correctly adressing the div. If somebody could help me to solve this problem I'll be very glad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no element with class "navbar" or "container", so this one won't do anything:

```
@media screen  and (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar > .container .navbar-brand,
    .navbar > .container-fluid .navbar-brand > img {
        min-width: 200px;
    }
}
```

This one should work, though the selector is perhaps a bit over-specific;  `.navbar-brand img` would be sufficient.

```
@media screen  and (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-collapse > .navbar-header > .navbar-brand > img {
        min-width: 200px;
    }
}
```

(But if the image is over 200px wide in the first place, adding a min-width won't have any effect.  There's also nothing here that would center the image.)

Comment: Really thanks, Daniel, very useful, it worked perfectly! Now I understand where was the error. Also sorry for the poor english! rsrs

Comment: No trouble, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You should take a conatiner for image and add position:relative. Now you can increase size of image and centerize horizontally as well as vertically.

```css
#img-container{
  position:relative;
}

#new-image{
  position:absolute;
  height:300px;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%);

}

#new-image{
  position:absolute;
  height:300px;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,50%);

}
```

```html
<div id="img-container">
   <img alt="Brand" src="img/logo_nomesistema.png"id="new-image">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To be responsive you would size your image to the biggest size (width) you want the logo to be on any device and add a "max-width: 100%" to make it scale down on smaller viewports. Adding "margin-left: auto" and margin-right: auto" will center it up.